# Wide to Long Categorical 0/1 Data Python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, reshape

I try to convert a pandas dataframe in some kind of Wide to Long way. My rows contains an ID (date x ASSIGNMENT), and a categorical 0/1 vector. I want a sparse data frame with each row containing the ID and a unique "1", the other categories being equal to 0.

To be clear, I have this:

```
submis = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1,3,4], 'ASSIGNMENT': ['Tel','CAT','Voiture'], 'SPLIT_1':[1,0,1],'SPLIT_2':[0,1,0], 'SPLIT_3':[1,1,0]}) 

  date ASSIGNMENT  SPLIT_1  SPLIT_2  SPLIT_3
     1        Tel        1        0        1
     3        CAT        0        1        1
     4    Voiture        1        0        0
```

I want this :

```
  date ASSIGNMENT  SPLIT_1  SPLIT_2  SPLIT_3
     1        Tel        1        0        0
     1        Tel        0        0        1
     3        CAT        0        1        0
     3        CAT        0        0        1
     4    Voiture        1        0        0
```

I did not manage to use wide/long format tools, and I could not find a comparable previous question. Could you please help me ?

Thanks !